# Which characters are legal for an xsd::string

Tags: xsd

Is there a limitation of the type of characters that are legal for an xsd::string (i.e. only letters  and numbers)?

Is a `@` for example legal to be contained it the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_string.asp, the xsd:string can contains:

> The string data type can contain characters, line feeds, carriage returns, and tab characters.

Also, characters means in the XML syntax every Unicode characters (including accents, symbol, etc.), so the @ is allowed. The only constraint is you need to escape <kbd>&</kbd>, <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> characters, for obvious reasons. Source: http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_string.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. Doesn't `@` fall under the category of `characters`?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong in fact. Again, according to http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_string.html (which refers to the XML syntax) says that any Unicode characters are allowed, with some exceptions (&, <, > has to be escaped)